# Omit graphics from data frame clipping?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, arcgis-10.5

I am trying to draw a set of arrows using the draw toolbar which point labels to certain features in my map in the layout view. I have data frame clipping set up and when I move the graphic outside of the clipping extent, it gets clipped too.

How can I omit the graphics from the data frame clipping?

Comment: Have you tried adding the graphics in Layout View rather than Data View?

Comment: Yes it happens in both views. Also have the same issue with text. It also gets clipped to the data frame.

Comment: Text I would expect but not graphic elements added (not just displayed) in layout view. I'm not able to test at the moment.

Comment: Ok I realised the issue, I had the Focus Data Frame selected so I was in fact creating them in the data view instead of the layout view. Working fine now.

Comment: I think you should write that up as a self-answer which is fine to do and should earn you some useful rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the Focus Data Frame option was selected which meant that the graphics were being created in the data view as opposed to the layout view, causing them to become clipped to the data frame along with the other data.

Once the graphics were created in the layout view the clipping was no longer being applied.